# Excel 2013 VBA IsEmpty/HasFormula - conceptual

Tags: excel, vba

Just starting out with VBA and wanted to ask a conceptual question. If I want to check if a cell contains a formula I use the HasFormula PROPERTY, but if I want to know if a cell is empty I use the IsEmpty FUNCTION. To me these seem like two kinds of the same operation. Is there a conceptual reason one is a property and the other a function?

Answer (score 0):

A cell containing a formula that returns *Null* will return *False* from IsEmpty(), but an empty cell will return *True*:

```
Sub HowEmptyIsIt()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")

    r.Formula = "="""""
    MsgBox IsEmpty(r)
    r.Clear
    MsgBox IsEmpty(r)

End Sub
```